# How to execute url for 9:00PM to 6:00AM only?

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, cron

I want to execute url automatic at night 9:00PM to 6:00AM. because I my cron job not working properly and I used AWS server with magento. so I want to create my custom cron in magento.

Comment: What do you mean by "execute url automatic"? A cron will execute a give task at a set time, so do you want to execute this take at 9:00, 9:01, 9:02 ...6:00?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call a specific url, you don't need a Magento cron. A system cronjob is enough in this case.

Just add this to your crontab (`crontab -e`):

To run every minute from 9AM to 6AM

```
* 0,1,2,3,4,5,21,22,23 * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent http://your-url-to-execute.com &>/dev/null
```

To run ONLY to every full hour:

```
0 0,1,2,3,4,5,21,22,23 * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent http://your-url-to-execute.com &>/dev/null
```

Comment: yes but I don't know how to and crontab in AWS(amazon web space) server

Comment: Log in via SSH, and then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470016/how-to-write-cron-job-in-aws-ec2-server